# Can I use angular when I have a Symfony 1.4 framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, symfony-1.4

I work with Symfony 1.4 framework; I would ask if I can add AngularJs to my project ? I would like to replace the ajax and jquery request by the code with AngularJs.
Is it compatible?

Example with my code where I need to replace it with AngularJs:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="<?php echo url_for('@target_ajax_time_options?reservation_id='.$reservation->getReservationId().'&reservation_user_id='.$tab[0]->getId().'&user_id='.$tab[0]->getUserId().'&car_category='.$reservation->getReservation()->getCarCategoryId().$redirect.'&retour='.$tab[0]->getRetour()); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems to be like a regular link with a route build up with symfony, where I don't understand where Angular could be helpful but, of course you can use angular inside your Symfony1.4 projects.

I'm actually doing that and it works perfectly!

The only thing you have to worry about is to correctly config angular, like you app name, scripts inclusions, and controller definitions.